# Today extension does not show my app icon in Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, icons, today-extension

I know about similar questions,  I did almost everything they suggested in these questions, but my icon app haven't appeared so far.

Why?

I use latest iOS 8.3 on both **device** and **simulator**. While it works on simulator it doesn't work on device. However if I try to **EDIT** my Today extensions, the icon, indeed, **IS VISIBLE** on the list. It means that the icon asset is visible for Today.

Below are my screens from **Device**:

[image]

and **Simulator**:

[image]

This is my IcoApp set
[image]

My icon on device is working:

[image]

This is my **icon.plist** for extension:

[image]

**For me it looks like a very big bug from Apple**

Comment: Does any icon show on device?

Comment: yes, my icon works on device.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a bug. Just tap to **EDIT** the widgets

[image]

Then remove your widget (you should see the icon of your widget here):

[image]

And add it again:

[image]

Now you can see your Today extension along with your icon :-)